# Why numpy.sum returns a float64 instead of an uint64 when adding elements of a generator?

Tags: python, numpy

I just came across this strange behaviour of [`numpy.sum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html):

```
>>> import numpy
>>> ar = numpy.array([1,2,3], dtype=numpy.uint64)
>>> gen = (el for el in ar)
>>> lst = [el for el in ar]
>>> numpy.sum(gen)
6.0
>>> numpy.sum(lst)
6
>>> numpy.sum(iter(lst))
<listiterator object at 0x87d02cc>
```

According to the documentation the result should be of the same `dtype` of the iterable, but then why in the first case a `numpy.float64` is returned instead of an `numpy.uint64`?
And how come the last example does not return any kind of sum and does not raise any error either?

Comment: As of 1.15, `np.sum(generator)` emits a warning telling you to use the builtin `sum` instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, numpy functions don't always do what you might expect when working with generators.  To create a numpy array, you need to know its size and type *before* creating it, and this isn't possible for generators.  So many numpy functions either don't work with generators, or do this sort of thing where they fall back on Python builtins.

However, for the same reason, using generators often isn't that useful in Numpy contexts.  There's no real advantage to making a generator from a Numpy object, because you already have to have the entire Numpy object in memory anyway.  If you need all the types to stay as you specify, you should just not wrap your Numpy objects in generators.

Some more info: Technically, the argument to `np.sum` is supposed to be an "array-like" object, not an iterable.  Array-like is defined [in the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) as:

> An array, any object exposing the array interface, an object whose `__array__` method returns an array, or any (nested) sequence.

The array interface is documented [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.interface.html).  Basically, arrays have to have a fixed shape and a uniform type.

Generators don't fit this protocol and so aren't really supported.  Many numpy functions are nice and will accept other sorts of objects that don't technically qualify as array-like, but a strict reading of the docs implies you can't rely on this behavior.  The operations may work, but you can't expect all the types to be preserved perfectly.

Comment: @Bakuriu: I updated my answer with some info and doc pointers.

Comment: Last thing: I suppose numpy considers `list`/`tuple`s as array-like even though they do not provide an `__array__` method, correct? But, then why returning a `list` from `__array__` raises an error? The quotation you posted says that it ought to be allowed since it is a sequence.

Comment: @Bakuriu: As I understand it, lists and tuples are sequences, and thus fit the definition of array-*like*, but they are not actually arrays (i.e., numpy arrays), and thus are not an appropriate return value for `__array__`.  There is a slight potential ambiguity in the way the definition is phrased, but the last bit about "any (nested) sequence" is one possible array-like, not a possible `__array__` return value.  An array-like can *be* a sequence or can have an `__array__` that returns an array, but it can't have an `__array__` that returns a sequence.

Answer (score 5):

If the argument is a generator, Python's builtin `sum` get used.

You can see this in the source code of `numpy.sum` (numpy/core/fromnumeric.py):

```
  0     if isinstance(a, _gentype):
  1         res = _sum_(a)
  2         if out is not None:
  3             out[...] = res
  4             return out
  5         return res
```

`_gentype` is just an alias of `types.GeneratorType`, and `_sum_` is alias of the built-in `sum`.

If you try applying `sum` to `gen` and `lst`, you could see that the results are the same: `6.0`.

The second parameter of `sum` is `start`, which defaults to *0*, this is part of what makes your result a `float64`.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: type(np.uint64(1) + np.uint64(2))
Out[2]: numpy.uint64

In [3]: type(np.uint64(1) + 0)
Out[3]: numpy.float64
```

**EDIT**:
BTW, I find a ticket on this issue, which is marked as a `wontfix`: http://projects.scipy.org/numpy/ticket/669

Comment: Could you explain better why the sum is an integer when the dtype of the array is `int64` but a float when the dtype is `uint64`?

Comment: @Bakuriu Researching ;) I will update my answer if I find anything new.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the explanation. Your answer ought to deserve more than mine upvote.